# Are the bounding boxes created using regionprops, parallel to the coordinate axes?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to calculate the x,y-coordinates of the four corners of the boundary box using the upper left coordinates and the widths which are already provided by the code

```
cc= bwconncomp(img);
stats_bb= regionprops(cc,'boundingbox');
```

But I need to know if the bounding boxes holding the connected components are parallel to the co-ordinate axes?

Comment: yes. it is in the form of `[ul_corner width]`, such that `ul_corner` is an 1X2 vector of the x,y coordinates of the upper-left corner, and `width` is an 1X2 vector specifying the width and hight of the box.

Comment: why don't you just try and see for yourself...

Comment: i did try but there was no way of knowing if the bounding box was actually parallel to the x,y-coordinate axes